# Pandas - Merge smaller dataframe onto a larger one

Tags: python, pandas

I've got 2 data frames like this,

df1:

```
columnA  columnB columnC
data1    2       d       
data1    2       d
data1    2       d
data2    3       r
data2    3       r
data3    4       g
data3    4       g
```

df2:

```
columnA   columnD  columnE
data1     a        x
data1     a        x    
data1     a        x
data2     b        y
data2     b        y
```

After merging I want the output like below,

Expected output:

```
columnA  columnB columnC columnD columnE
data1    2       d       a       x
data1    2       d       a       x
data1    2       d       a       x
data2    3       r       b       y
data2    3       r       b       y
data3    4       g
data3    4       g
```

Is there a way to do this?

I've tried,
`combined = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", on="columnA")` but this results in more rows than originally.

Comment: Try this `df_concat = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`

Comment: @Salahuddin this creates a second `columnA` column

Comment: I think this is better :) df_concat = pd.concat([df, df2.drop(['columnA'], axis=1)], axis=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to remove the duplicates from your second dataframe:

```
df2_nodup = df2.drop_duplicates()
```

Now you can use `pd.merge()` to create the desired output:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2_nodup, how='left')
  columnA  columnB columnC columnD columnE
0   data1        2       d       a       x
1   data1        2       d       a       x
2   data1        2       d       a       x
3   data2        3       r       b       y
4   data2        3       r       b       y
5   data3        4       g     NaN     NaN
6   data3        4       g     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by simply using [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) :

```
combined = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).fillna('')
```

##### `>>> print(combined)`

[image]

> **Documentation**: pandas.concat() concatenate pandas objects along a particular axis with optional set logic along the other axes. Can also add a layer of hierarchical indexing on the concatenation axis, which may be useful if the labels are the same (or overlapping) on the passed axis number.

[image]